# How can I use the Socket.IO client though ES6 modules?

Tags: ember.js, websocket, socket.io, ember-cli

I am currently working with Ember.js using the Ember-CLI.
The application uses ES6 modules to import the required functions to each "module".

I am going to use web sockets to connect to the API and I would like to find some examples of how to import socket.io as a ES6 module.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the accepted answer?  I'm stuck with the same problem [SO Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29025058/1438809).

Comment: Hi, which part are you stuck on? Check out https://github.com/Wildhoney/EmberSockets

Comment: Ended up changing to [socket.io-client](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client), which worked for me.  Thanks for responding!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to message me if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to app.import it in your Brocfile, then export default window.socketio

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? Where does one put the "export default window.socketio"?

Comment: I am assuming that this is intended to be done using Ember.js' 'app.import' function. If you do this inside a js file in your source that represents the 'socket.io-client' module, then you would 'export default' from that. This would give you a nice interface for socket.io-client where you can import it as through it were of your files.

** Assume **

Answer (score 0):

1. Get socket.io-client by bower

   **bower install socket.io-client**
2. import the library as 'io':

Example:

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function (data) {
  console.log('Connected!');
  socket.emit('message', {message:"Hello!"});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here: [How to use Socket.io with Next.js, Express...](https://wallis.dev/blog/socketio-with-nextjs-and-es6-import)

```js
import * as socketio from 'socket.io';
const io = new socketio.Server();
io.attach(server);
```