# How to import socket.io via brocfile for ember cli application?

Tags: import, ember-cli, broccolijs

I want to use [socket.io](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io) in my ember cli application, so I installed with:

```
bower install socket.io --save
```

And added the following line to my `Brocfile.js`:

```
app.import('bower_components/socket.io/index.js');
```

This results in two errors in my browser console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-moment/helpers/moment
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up using [socket.io-client](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-client) which imports without errors.

```
app.import('bower_components/socket.io-client/socket.io.js');
```

Comment: how do you import it on the ember service side?

Comment: @ᐅdevrimbaris I'm not sure, I haven't touched ember in a long time :/